# Report Server integration mode in SharePoint 2010 farm

Tags: sharepoint, sql, ssrs, sharepoint-2010

I have a SharePoint 2010 farm that consists of four servers - two WFE servers and two app servers. The WFE servers are the only servers that serve requests to the portal (which is behind a load balancer). The app servers host CA and assorted service applications.

I want to configure SSRS 2008 in SharePoint integrated mode. I already have a SSRS 2008 server built that has an instance of SSRS in non-integrated mode, and I would like to repurpose this server for the SharePoint reporting. My questions are:

1) Do I have to add the SSRS server as a WFE in the existing farm? The documentation claims that I do, but is it possible to have the Reporting Services add-in installed on an existing WFE and then it just points to the SSRS server?

2) If I do need SSRS on a server in the farm, does it have to be a WFE, or can I install it on one of the app servers, keeping in mind that they never serve requests directly to clients?

Answer (score 0):

1) You have to make the SSRS server itself a member of your SharePoint farm, just pointing the addin to a standalone SSRS server won't do the trick.

2) You can install it on one of the web tier servers in your farm, it does not have to be on a server in your app tier. Installing SharePoint 2010 on the existing SSRS server does the trick too of course, so you'll end up with 5 servers in your farm.

A nice overview can be found [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326356.aspx).

Comment: I'm thinking it will get installed on a WFE...I don't want to add another server to the farm and pay the server tax just to get SSRS up :)